Inequality involving random vectors and absolute values
Let $\mathbb{X}, \mathbb{Y} \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be finite sets. Suppose random vectors $X \in \mathbb{X}$ and $Y \in \mathbb{Y}$ are sampled according to a joint distribution $\mathbb{P}_{XY}$. Additionally, define a random vector $\hat{Y}$, which has the same marginal distribution as $Y$, but is independent of $X$.
We know that the following inequality holds:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X^\top Y - \mathbb{E}\left[X^\top \hat{Y} \mid X\right]\right]^2
    \leq
        d \cdot
        \mathbb{E}\left[
            \left(X^\top \hat{Y} - \mathbb{E}\left[X^\top \hat{Y} \mid X\right]\right)^2
        \right],
$$
which itself is a direct consequence of this inequality:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X^\top Y\right]^2
    \leq
        d \cdot
        \mathbb{E}\left[
            \left(X^\top \hat{Y}\right)^2
        \right].
$$
I think the following inequality also holds:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[|X^\top Y| - \mathbb{E}\left[|X^\top \hat{Y}| \mid X\right]\right]^2
    \leq
        d \cdot
        \mathbb{E}\left[
            \left(|X^\top \hat{Y}| - \mathbb{E}\left[|X^\top \hat{Y}| \mid X\right]\right)^2
        \right],
$$
but I can't prove it, so I'm looking for a proof!
P.s. I can provide the proof of the other inequalities if needed.

It could indeed help if you provide proofs of your statements (or references to them, if available).

Let $h = E[Y], and V = E[X X^t]$ be invertible for simplicity.
The LHS is
$$E[X^t Y - E[X^t \hat Y | X ]]=E[X^t (Y - h)]\leq E[|X|_{V^{-1}}|Y - h|V]\leq\sqrt{E[|X|{V^{-1}}^2]E[|\hat Y - h|V^2]}$$
Further
$$E[|X|{V^{-1}}^2]=E[tr(X^t E[X X^t]^{-1} X)]=tr(E[X X^t] E[X X^t]^{-1})= d.$$
Moreover,
$$E[|\hat Y - h|_V^2]=E[(\hat Y - h)^t E[X X^t] (\hat Y - h)]=E[(\hat Y - h)^t X X^t (\hat Y - h)]=E[(X^t (\hat Y - h))^2]=E[(X^t \hat Y - E[X^t \hat Y | X])^2]$$

I hope it's clear:)
I didn't include the proof in the main question since from my experience long questions have significantly less chance for getting a response..

I have something that may help. As the first proof start from the fact that
$$\mathbb E[X^\top Y]^2\le d\mathbb E[(X^\top \hat Y)^2],$$
it may be useful to generalize it to the absolute value, getting
$$\mathbb E[|X^\top Y|]^2\le d\mathbb E[(X^\top \hat Y)^2].$$
We can prove this by defining an auxiliary random vector, $Y'$ that is equal to $Y$ when $X^\top Y>0$ and $-Y$ otherwise. Applying the original inequality to $Y'$, we get the result.

Indeed, $|X^\top Y|=X^\top Y'$ almost surely. Moreover, as for any vector $v$ we have $(v^\top \hat Y')^2=(v^\top Y')^2=(v^\top Y)^2=(v^\top \hat Y)^2$, we have also $$\mathbb E[(X^\top \hat Y')^2]=\mathbb E[(X^\top \hat Y)^2]$$
